# Book with dwindling crew entering codes to prevent destruction from computer problems

Tags: story-identification, novel

When I was younger I found a book from an author I had not heard of before but can’t remember it’s name or the author.

The scene is a spaceship on a mission in deep space. The crew (I think there were 4) were I think 2 girls and 2 boys (actually thinking about it now I think there were 5 crew).

They controlled the ship with the help of the on board computer doing surveying or something, and were in formed seats that held them in place except for their head and their right arms. The controls were in the form of a mini keyboard under their hands.

At the end of the book, the computer had gone insane and killed all but one girl, who had to keep entering an override code every 5 hours and was slowly falling asleep due to exhaustion and when she missed putting the code in she would die. The code was actually designed to be in 4/5 parts with each crew knowing one part, but all crew had the other members codes subliminally embedded in their minds, so she knew all the codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nightrider** by David Mace

The ship is a military vessel equipped with an experimental stealth drive. It is sent on a mission to destroy an enemy base on a trans Plutonian planet. During the mission the ship's computer becomes deranged and starts killing the crew. The surviving person has to lie in her form fitting control couch ans use thr hand keyboards to periodically enter computer over ride codes.